# Recursion seems not working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am writing a piece of code to recursively processing *.py files. The code block is as the following:

```
class FileProcessor(object):

    def convert(self,file_path):
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            """ If the path is a directory,then process it recursively 
                untill a file is met"""
            dir_list=os.listdir(file_path)
            print("Now Processing Directory:",file_path)

            i=1

            for temp_dir in dir_list:
                print(i,":",temp_dir)
                i=i+1
                self.convert(temp_dir)
        else:
            """ if the path is not a directory"""
            """ TODO something meaningful """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tempObj=FileProcessor()
    tempObj.convert(sys.argv[1])
```

When I run the script with a directory path as argument, it only runs the first layer of the directory, the line:

```
self.convert(temp_dir)
```

seems never get called. I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: there's a better way to do this btw. [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursion is happening fine, but `temp_dir` is not a directory so it passes control to your stub `else` block. You can see this if you put `print(file_path)` outside your `if` block.

`temp_dir` is the ***name*** of the next directory, not its absolute path. `"C:/users/adsmith/tmp/folder"` becomes just `"folder"`. Use `os.path.abspath` to get that

```
self.convert(os.path.abspath(temp_dir))
```

Although the canonical way to do this (as mentioned in my comment on the question) is to use `os.walk`.

```
class FileProcessor(object):
    def convert(self, file_path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
            # if file_path is C:/users/adsmith, then:
            #   root == C:/users/adsmith
            #   dirs is an iterator of each directory in C:/users/adsmith
            #   files is an iterator of each file in C:/users/adsmith
            # this walks on its own, so your next iteration will be
            # the next deeper directory in `dirs`

            for i, d in enumerate(dirs):
                # this is also preferred to setting a counter var and incrementing
                print(i, ":", d)
                # no need to recurse here since os.walk does that itself
            for fname in files:
                # do something with the files? I guess?
```

Comment: thanks a lot. detailed explanation and nice example,helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As `temp_dir` has the filename only without parent path, you should change

```
self.convert(temp_dir)
```

to

```
self.convert(os.path.join(file_path, temp_dir))
```